# Can we get an annual survey?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, annual-survey

I just took the 2019 Developer Survey for Stack Overflow, and I was thinking it would be cool to get similar information for the RPG.se community.

Some potential questions:

- What RPGs have you played within the last 12 months?
- What RPG are you planning to play within 12 months?
- What RPG do you currently play the most?
- Which of these reflects your opinion on meta-gaming?
- Which of these reflects your playstyle (optimiser, roleplayer, etc.)?
- How often do you play as the GM/Facilitator/etc..?
- What originally attracted you to RPG.SE?

I don't know if this has been discussed before or what it would take to achieve, but I would be interested to see the results.

Comment: I like the idea, but I think we'd have be really careful not to restrict questions to the D&D paradigm (meta-gaming as a concept makes no sense in most of the RPGs I play) or reinforce common false dichotomies (like [optimisation vs roleplaying](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/22251/4398)).

Comment: @BESW In the main survey every question has the option "Not relevant to me" or "Prefer not to say" or similar. That should be ok for system restricted questions?

Comment: @BESW also in the main survey options were not mutually exclusive, you can be both a heavy roleplayer and a optimizer.

Comment: Related on Meta SE? [Survey of users to judge quality and culture of an SE site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308753)

Comment: This would be cool but I don’t think it’s likely. The dev survey provides SE corporate with info core to their business strategies, and they share it because it’s cool info. I’d be surprised if there’s a business case for surveying any other topic.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie It might not be quite as official or supported or well-presented as the official Developer Survey, but if a survey for this stack is desired then someone could reasonably make one in Google Forms or similar and just post it on Meta. That said, my experience with similar things is that "someone could" typically means "nobody does".

Comment: @SevenSidedDie While you're right that corporate is highly unlikely to give us a survey like the one the main site gets, Kamil Drakari is right that there's nothing stopping us from making our own. I've created a meta question [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8754/3548) gauging interest in doing so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No.**

Community Manager Catija dropped by mod chat and said basically they wouldn't be doing that but we could do an informal one ourselves, with an additional caution to use a very anonymous one and to perhaps stick to site topics and not things that will stir controversy like demographics.

Comment: ...Did she explain how/why asking about demographics would "stir controversy"? Seems a bit of a strange claim to me...

Comment: No, it was a very brief interaction. Since current votes are to not do our own either, I will place it in the "don't care" section of my mind.