# What questions should an annual RPG survey ask?

Tags: discussion, annual-survey

I recently asked a question about [getting an annual survey](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8741/48759) similar to the official developer survey. The current consensus to this is "unlikely".

Following that Oblivous Sage asked if [we wanted to make our own](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8754/48759). To which the current assumption is "yes but what would we ask? and who would make it?". I will leave that question to deal with who is actually going to create the survey.

This question is to serve as a gathering post for the questions we want to ask. Highly voted responses should reflect what the community is actually curious about.

Answer (score 9):

## Questions related to systems and what people are playing

#### What RPGs have you played within the last 12 months (select all that apply)?

*Sourced from top 10 system tags for brevity, more options should be included in actual survey*

- Dungeons and Dragons 5th Edition
- Pathfinder
- Dungeons and Dragons 3/3.5 Edition
- Dungeons and Dragons 4th Edition
- World of Darkness
- Savage Worlds
- Fate
- Dungeon World
- Chronicles of Darkness 1st Edition
- Shadowrun 5th Edition
- Other (Specify)

#### What RPGs have you run/GMed within the last 12 months (select all that apply)?

*As above*

#### What RPGs are you planning to play within 12 months (select all that apply)?

*As above*

#### What RPGs are you planning to run/GM within 12 months (select all that apply)?

*As above*

#### What RPGs do you want to play within 12 months (select all that apply)?

*As above*

#### What RPGs do you want to run/GM within 12 months (select all that apply)?

*As above*

#### What RPGs do you currently play the most (select one)?

*As above*

#### If you were to start a new game which RPG are you most likely to play (select one)?

*As above*

#### If you were to start a new game which RPG are you most likely to run/GM (select one)?

*As above*

Comment: It would be better with a more comprehensive list of games, with a "played in last year", "GMed in last year," "want to play", "want to GM" options.

Comment: @mxyzplk Absolutely the list should be longer, I just didn't want this post to get stupid long so I just included the top 10 tags. I'll edit to include the gm questions.

Comment: We might steal a page from the SO survey and ask what games respondents *want* to play next year.

Comment: No, it really isn't. If I really *want* to play, say, Don't Rest Your Head, but nobody else I play RPGs with is interested, then I'm probably not *planning* to play it. What people *want* to play and what they *plan/expect* to play are different things, and it's worth asking about both.

Comment: @ObliviousSage I added those questions. Do you think it requires both questions or would "want/plan to play" suffice?

Comment: SO asks both separately, I think we should as well.

Answer (score 6):

## Questions about the site

#### What originally attracted you to RPG.SE (select one)?

- Rules question
- Homebrew
- Hot network questions
- Other (specify)

#### How often do you visit RPG.SE (select one)?

- Daily
- 2-3 times a week
- Weekly
- 2-3 times a month
- Monthly
- Less than once a month

#### How often do you participate in RPG.SE, i.e. post a question, answer, vote or comment (select one)?

*As above*

#### Which other Stack Exchange sites do you use regularly (select up to three)?

*Suggestions for more options welcome*

- Stack Overflow
- Worldbuilding
- Board & Card Games
- Arqade
- Writing
- Interpersonal
- Other (specify)

Comment: For the question about other SE sites you use, Interpersonal (aka IPS) might be a good option to include, given the semi-frequent overlap.

Answer (score 6):

## Questions on demographics

We should copy the official developer survey for these questions as they are difficult to get the wording to be inclusive. Results from 2018 survey can be found [here](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018/#demographics).

Questions include:

- Age
- Gender
- Race
- Education
- Sexual Orientation
- Location

Important to note, this survey is completely anonymous. Questions like this are to ensure we are serving all member of our community equally.

Comment: Comments from CMs in chat have indicated we should avoid asking demographic information. These questions will either need to be very broad, or not included.

Answer (score 2):

## More suggestions

### Why do you play RPGs? (select all that apply)

Not sure how to put this into a survey format; fill in the blank seems like a bad option.    Maybe like 'fun/personal improvement/professional/other(specify)'?

### How often do you engage with RPG-related material?

Several times a day/ once a day/ several times a week/ once a week/ a couple of times a month/ infrequently

### How often do you play RPGs?

Never/yearly/monthly/biweekly/weekly/more than once a week

### How often do you GM RPGs?

Never/yearly/monthly/biweekly/weekly/more than once a week

Answer (score 2):

## Suggested Questions

### Questions regarding the way people play

(following the dark wanderer's suggestion)

- **For how long have you been playing RPGs?** General experience argument.
- **When did you first play an RPG?** Also help with demographics.
- **How did you discover RPGs?** Through Friend/Family/Event/Internet/Other
- **Which RPG do you have the most experience with?** On which games is our community the most able to help, and on which are we lacking?

### Questions regarding the way people use the stack

- **What tag do you come for here the most?** i.e. what do you require help with?
- **Why do you visit rpg.stackExchange** Fun & relax / Learn new things / Help other / Find answers to question. Why people visit the stack?
- **Did rpg.stackExchange improve your game experience as a player?**
- **Did rpg.stackExchange improve your game experience as a GM?**

Answer (score 0):

### Suggested Questions

#### Did playing RPGs improve your friendships and relationships?

RPGs are a social activity, and a lot of games have a learning element to them (whether intended or unintended).  Likewise, if by interacting socially in this kind of game environment one's friendships and relationships were improved, I think that would be interesting to learn (or to what extent).

#### Did playing RPGs hurt or help your GPA, grades, or other measurable school performance marks?

(College/High School audience mostly)

#### Did playing RPGs influence your relationships at work?

(There's [a Q&A over at workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/84746/64595) that suggests that such a thing can happen ...)

Comment: Regarding your GPA question, from what I know of education in other countries, GPA is also not a global concept. Might be worth considering. Also the work question seems sort of a subset of the overall friendships/relationships question.

Comment: @V2Blast Not if we take a look at that question ... and I do need to consider a better term than GPA except  that there won't be a survey.